# vim-like quickfix plugin for CLion

Tags: clion, vim-quickfix

There is amazing feature in vim called quickfix (don't remember if it's plugin or the native thing), it allows one to iterate over errors in editor by moving cursor to the location of the error.

How can I setup the same functionality in CLion with Rust plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by pressing `F2` key:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-to-next-previous-error.html

Comment: Thank you for response! I've seen this page, `F2` allows one to iterate over errors in *code inspection*, not compiler errors, or there is something wrong with my CLion